# Check a value from the database

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get a value from the database. If this value is equal to 1, it needs to show the text "One".

But my script is not working. To check if the result of the sql statement is equal to 1 i am using the following part:

```
if ($result==1)

    {
        echo 'One'; 
    }
```

But this is the result I get:

```
else
    {
    echo 'None';
    }
```

I think that `$result==1` is not representing a integer.

Does anybody know how I can make this script working?

Here is other part of my script:

```
<?php

$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "db";
$server = "localhost";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {
$result =mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_id=1");
if ($result==1)

    {
        echo 'One'; 
    }

if ($result==2)

    {
        echo 'Two'; 
    }

if ($result==3)

    {
        echo 'Three'; 
    }

else
    {
    echo 'None';
    }
}
else {
print "Database NOT Found.";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `mysql_num_rows` to check weather your query return rows or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this :

```
$result =mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_id=1");
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {
    echo 'One'; 
}
```

and so on

**Note :-** The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

If you want exact value from sql, use below code :

```
$res = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($res[0] == 1) {
    echo 'One'; 
}
```

Comment: Now I get the text "One". But if I change the value of `id` to `2`. I still get "One"

Comment: Obviously the count is still 1. If you want the actual id then please use mysql_fetch_row or such function which will return the exact value and use that instead of mysql_num_row. I have update my answer accordingly.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" }

Comment: Okay I have updated the code check once. It should be if ($res[0] == 1)

Comment: Cool. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
  <?php

    $user_name = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "db";
    $server = "localhost";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {
    $result =mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE user_id = 1");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);}
    if($result){
        echo $result['id'];

    }
    else
        {
        echo 'None';
        }

    mysql_close($db_handle);
    ?>
```